# Recover character with scanf in c

Tags: c, character, scanf

I am currently doing exercices on Kattis and I meet a problem at the time of recovering the character of scanf...
I manage to recover my characters before my conditions but not during these latter...

**Here is my code with comments to target my problems**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bela(int m, char c)
{
    char card[2];
    int point = 0;

    printf("0 = %c\n",c); // Here c = my enter of scanf
    for(int i = 0; i != m * 4; i += 1) {
        scanf("%s", card);
        for(int i = 0; card[i] != '\0'; i += 1) {
            if(card[i] == 'A') {
                point = point + 11;
                printf("A = %i\n", point);
            }
            if(card[i] == 'K') {
                point = point + 4;
                printf("K = %i\n", point);
            }
            if(card[i] == 'Q') {
                point = point + 3;
                printf("Q = %i\n", point);
            }
            printf("1 = %c\n",c); // Here c = nothing instead of the value of c
            if(card[i] == 'J' && card[i + 1] == c) { // Here c can not to be compared since he's equal to nothing...
                point = point + 20;
                printf("%c", card[i + 1]);// Here card[i + 1] = nothing instead of the value of c
            } 
            else if(card[i] == 'J' && card[i + 1] != c)
                point = point + 2;
            if(card[i] == 'T') {
                point = point + 10;
                printf("T = %i\n", point);
            }
            if(card[i] == '9' && card[i + 1] == c) {
                point = point + 14;
                printf("9 + S %i\n", point);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n", point);
}

int main(void)
{
    int m = 0;
    char c = 0;

    scanf("%i %c", &m, &c);
    bela(m, c);
    return (0);
}
```

Do you have any ideas for solve the problems ?

Thanks for your help.

PtiCassarin

Comment: Are you entering only _one_ character to read `card`? Otherwise you could be overwriting the stack and so overwrite the parameter `c`.

Comment: No you are not. Conclusion: `card` is too small. You probably forget the terminating null character, so declare as `card[3]`. Also read it with`"%2s"` so you do not read more than can fit in the buffer

Comment: Never ever do: `scanf("%s", card);` use `fgets` instead (or at least `scanf("%1s", card);`)

Comment: You may want to read this: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: Thank's to all of you, it works ! 

Comment: This problems it's my declare of card

Comment: Is [bela](https://open.kattis.com/problems/bela) the problem you're solving?